# How to fetch an online array to a VueJs app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an online array [online array link](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments)
that I want to add to my VueJs project I use this code:

```
    
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")  
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => console.log(json))
    .then(json => {
    this.lists = json.lists
  })
```

from VueMastery at Vue.org but it doesn't work, gives me an error Json.lists isn't defined

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line

```
  then((json) => console.log(json))
```

You are returning `console.log(json)` it doesnt make sense

If you want still to log it do it like this

```
  then(json => {
      console.log(json);
      return json;
   })
```